# c# use object before it's created

Tags: c#, winforms, events, controls

I dynamic create and trackbar on an event,
now i want a textbox tto be filled with the value of the trackbar.

but how am i possible to do that? since i'll get an error saying the dynamic created trackbar does not exist. which is logic

this is what i have so far.

```
        TrackBar trackBar = new TrackBar();
        trackBar.Name = "TrackbarWidth" + trackbarName++;
        trackBar.Tag = "dispose";
        trackBar.Maximum = 85;
        trackBar.Minimum = 65;
        trackBar.SmallChange = 5;
        trackBar.TickFrequency = 5;
        trackBar.Value = WidthValue;
        trackBar.Location = new Point(175, 440 + (50 * trackbarName));
        trackBar.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 25);
        this.Controls.Add(trackBar);

        TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
        textBox.Name = "TrackbarWidth" + TextboxName++;
        textBox.Text = trackBar.Value.ToString();
        textBox.Tag = "dispose";
        textBox.Location = new Point(300, 440 + (50 * TextboxName));
        textBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(30, 25);
        this.Controls.Add(textBox);

        lineWidth += 4;
    }
#endregion
}

private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e){
    textBox1.Text = trackBar1.Value.ToString();
}
```

The problem with this solution is that I cannot access the textbox or the trackbar in the `trackBar1_Scroll` method.

Comment: Where is trackbar1 being initialized?

Comment: The error is in the button trackbar1_scroll event. it says "trackbar1" and "textbox1"  do not exist, that's true. since they will be created dynamicly.

Comment: The trackbar1 is intialized on a listbox.selectedIndexChanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution here to use use an anonymous event handler that is capable of closing over the two variables that you need.  Include this just after you finish constructing the textbox:

```
this.Controls.Add(textBox);
trackBar.Scroll += (s, args) => {
    textbox.Text = trackbar.Value.ToString();
};
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. all though i don't understand any of the 2nd line of code :)

Comment: @user1859829 It creates a new anonymous method and adds it as an event handler for the `Scroll` event.  In particular it's called a "Lambda", if you're interested in further reading on the subject.

Comment: Thank you, i rather understand the code and be able to recreate it on my own. than just copy paste it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The `sender` argument is always the control which triggered the event:

```
private void trackBar_Scroll(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // TextBox also dynamic? One way is using ControlCollection.Find
    textBox1 = this.Controls.Find("textBox1", true).FirstOrDefault() as TextBox;
    if(textBox1 != null)
        textBox1.Text = trackBar1.Value.ToString();
}
```

However, if you create it dynamically you also have to create the event handler:

```
TrackBar trackBar = new TrackBar();
trackBar.Scroll += this.trackBar_Scroll;
```

Comment: He still won't be able to access the textbox this way, only the trackbar.

Comment: Now, it ofcourse doesn't know textbox1 either, since it's created dynamicly. But i can't seem to get it working. Addin this " textBox.TextChanged += this.textBox_TextChanged;"  to the dynamic textbox creater should work right?

Comment: @Servy: Oh, the TextBox is also created dynamically?

Comment: @user1859829: If you know the name you can use `Controls.Find`. Edited my answer.